# How to create an excel file based on the HTML table and save it in the project directory

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, excel, html

I have build an HTML table and load data in it. What I want to do is, based on that table which contains data create(or convert) it to excel and save the excel file in the project directory.

Here is my HTML Table

```
 <table class='tblNemoList' border='1' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='-fs-table-paginate: paginate;'>
            $thChanges
            $trChanges
            $thMissing
            $trMissing
            $thNew
            $trNew
         </table>
      ";
      $strFilename = "FIM_KnowMore_Report_$DT";
```

And the excel conversion is here

```
header("Pragma: no-cache");
      header("Expires: 0");
      header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $strFilename .".xls"); //gets set inside the report.rpt.php
      file_put_contents($strFilename, $strBody);
```

I am missing the code to save it in a directory. Can you please help ?

Comment: Naming a html file. Xls does not magically make it an excel file

Comment: Okay. do you have an idea on how I should do it?

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Answer (score 1):

PHPExcel is a great library for creating and handling excel files with php.
give it a try.

[PHPExcel on GitHub](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)